# sql>vb.net date

Tags: sql, vb.net

so i was trying to fill a data grid view on my project 
and this is the code im sending from vb to sql

```
 SELECT f.nomeFornecedor, e.idEncomenda, p.nomeProduto,pe.quantidade,e.estado 
  FROM Fornecedor as f  INNER JOIN Encomenda AS e  ON f.idFornecedor = e.idFornededor 
   INNER JOIN Produto_Encomenda as pe  ON e.idEncomenda = pe.idEncomenda  
   INNER JOIN Produto as p  ON p.idProduto = pe.idProduto  
   where e.data='07/03/2017'
```

now on sql it works but when i try to do it from the datagridview on the program only shows the menu tab  but on the other hand if i try to fill my grid without "where e.data='07/03/2017'
it works. im kinda lost here :\
here is the code from vb

```
Private Sub loadGrid()

        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Dim sqlStr As String = " SELECT f.nomeFornecedor, e.idEncomenda, p.nomeProduto,pe.quantidade "
        sqlStr += " FROM Fornecedor as f "
        sqlStr += " INNER JOIN Encomenda AS e "
        sqlStr += " ON f.idFornecedor = e.idFornededor "
        sqlStr += " INNER JOIN Produto_Encomenda as pe "
        sqlStr += " ON e.idEncomenda = pe.idEncomenda "
        sqlStr += " INNER JOIN Produto as p "
        sqlStr += " ON p.idProduto = pe.idProduto "
       'if i erase the query filter aka where data (...) it works 
        queryFilter = " where e.data='" & mrData & "' "
        sqlStr += queryFilter

        ' MsgBox(sqlStr, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "controlo")
        ' Set up the DataGridView.
        With Me.DataGridView1
            ' Set up the data source.
            BindingSource1.DataSource = CAD.GetData(sqlStr)
            .DataSource = BindingSource1

            ' Automatically resize the visible rows.
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders

            ' Set the DataGridView control's border.
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None

        End With
    End Sub
  'this is the function (is in a class thats why its public)
   Public Shared Function GetData(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable


        Dim connectionString As String = myDAC._connectionString

        Dim constr As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlCommand, constr)
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = command

        Dim table As New DataTable
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        adapter.Fill(table)

        Return table
    End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of the variable holding your query prior to execution?  You probably have some issue injecting the value causing the query to break.  You should really start using parameterized queries instead of string concatenation.  It prevents problems like this one as well as protects against SQL Injection so that [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) doesn't come and visit.

Comment: yes i did but i cant send any prints because i dont have any reputation on this website . but the value of the string that im connecting to sql it works on the sql when i copy to it but i dont know why i doesnt when the program runs it, even more odd is the fact that the only thing that makes it not to work is the where part

Comment: You don't need to literally print it or screenshot it (pictures of code are very frowned upon) - just copy/paste the value of the variable into your question.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it doesn't work?"  Are you just getting different results?  If so, that could have something to do with the format of your date.  (e.g. Is it meant to be July 3rd or March 7th?)  Try changing the format of your date to the ISO standard of `yyyy-mm-dd`.  The compiler might be interpreting your date as July 3rd, causing no results to be returned.

Comment: What is the datatype of Mr. Data?  Have you tried adding parameters to your query instead of concatenating? concatenating isn't a very good idea...

Comment: siyual i what i mean by it doesnt work is that no data appears on the datagridview but there is no exeption . about the format if it was a format problem then it should pop up an exeption os sql type right?

Comment: and btw the string sqlstr = " SELECT f.nomeFornecedor as Fornecedor, e.idEncomenda as nºEncomenda, p.nomeProduto as Produto,pe.quantidade,e.estado as 'Estado da encomenda' FROM Fornecedor as f  INNER JOIN Encomenda AS e  ON f.idFornecedor = e.idFornededor  INNER JOIN Produto_Encomenda as pe  ON e.idEncomenda = pe.idEncomenda  INNER JOIN Produto as p  ON p.idProduto = pe.idProduto  where e.data='07/03/2017' " and when i copy paste it to sql it works .. like it shows the data i want but for come reason through vb it does not :\

Comment: the_lotus : its a string and its like this ->  Private mrData As String = FormatDateTime(Now(), DateFormat.ShortDate)

Comment: you should use the Date type, both in SQL and in VB.NET, to store your value. Then you don't need to worry about the format so much (only in the UI, not everywhere else). At the moment, your string is ambiguous - it could mean 3rd July or March 7th. How it's interpreted will depend on the settings in MySQL and in your server.

Comment: well i figure out how to solve, i added SET language portuguese; on the string and it solved it .